# Is it safe to globally store and reuse a UIViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Is it safe to globally store `UIViewController` instances created by

```
UIViewController *myController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewID"];
```

and reuse them? What would happen if the memory runs low? Would iOS free some of the previously instantiated, but inactive UIViewControllers?

The reason why I'm asking is because some of the UIViewControllers are quite memory intense. Further, the app is structured in a way that makes various UIViewControllers accessible from each other and I'd like to avoid wasting memory by having various instances if only one instance is sufficient.

I was just curious if there are any situations where iOS would remove/free any (invisible) UIViewControllers, like for example, when the memory runs low.

Comment: Why are you considering doing it? How will it help you?

Comment: View Controllers aren't special, when it comes to memory management.  No one will automatically release them, unless you're using `NSCache` or a similar class.  If you keep references, it's your job to listen for memory warnings and release them.

Comment: `Is it safe`?  It *could* be done in a safe way, probably.  But to answer the question you're not asking... is it a good idea?  As a rule, no.  There are potentially exceptions to this rule, but none that I'm aware of.

Comment: Typically, there is no reason to do that because it brings additional problems. There are some specific use cases when it can be a valid idea, e.g. to minimize performance impact of the controller loading but I don't think that creating a really global controller can be justified.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? And what additional problems could it cause? Please explain in a little more detail.

Comment: According to MVC pattern, all views are dumb and ViewController is his brain and everything (owner). So a view should belong to only "1" ViewController and it's not a good idea to save Views or viewControllers.
Only you should store Modal's and nothing else.
Rest it all depends on requirement and situation.

Comment: You could have a singleton that holds a property which references your viewcontroller, so in your app initialization you only load your viewcontroller once and can access it later through your singleton

Comment: Thank you for the advise so far. I'm willing to accept a "Don't do this because of that" kind of explanation/answer. So far I understand that it would break the MVP pattern, but the actual problem are the scarce resources/memory and managing it myself seems like a better idea if the result is more stable than it would be by blindly following a design pattern. The end justifies the means. So I guess I'm gonna stick with instantiating the UIViewControllers just once and reusing them.